# Looking up a model property's value in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I don't even know how to properly title this question.

Here's the question:
I have a model whose attributes contain values that are IDs of rows in other tables.

Example:

```
Person['type'] = 108
```

In another table, the value for ID '108' would equal "Full Time".

Currently my model returns with the value:

```
Person['type'] = 108
```

Instead I want my model to be returned with the value associated with '108', like this:

```
Person['type'] = "Full Time"
```

In the related table, the column names are:
"id" and "optionValue"

How would I go about doing this in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a basic relationship between those tables. So you just have to

Define your PersonType model:

```
class PersonType extends Eloquent {

}
```

Define your Person model and add the relationship to it:

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('PersonType');
    }

}
```

EDIT

If your tables doesn't follow the Laravel naming system (person_type_id), you will have to

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('PersonType', 'type');
    }

}
```

/EDIT

Now you can find a person:

```
$person = Person::find(1);
```

And print the type this way:

```
echo $person->type->name;
```

It should print "Full Time".

I'm assuming that your person_types table has a 'name' column where you store your types names.

Comment: This returns a null value as 'type'. My person object has a type attribute containing an id value from another table. The 'type' with that id in the other table is not specific to the person. The model for my person is titled "personnel", it looks like this:

Comment: Continued edit: 
   class Personnel extends Eloquent{
 protected $table = 'personnel';
 public $type; 
 public function type(){
  return $this->belongsTo('PersonnelType');
 }
}


PersonnelType model looks like this:
   class PersonnelType extends Eloquent{
 protected $table = 'options';
 public function personnel(){
  return $this->belongsTo('Personnel', 'type');
 }
}

Comment: I went back and added a foreign_key param to the belongsTo and now it works:  return $this->belongsTo('PersonType', 'type')

Comment: Just edited to support your column names. You should think about renaming your columns, to follow the Laravel way or you'll have to make a lot of this during your coding. Your tables should look like this: `table person (id, name, person_type_id) = Person Model Class / table person_types (id, name) = PersonType Model Class`, doing this way things are automatic in Laravel. But, of course, you're free to do the way you prefer, it will just give you more things to think of.